# Chrome changes Poster image on mouse hover with Afterglow HTML5 Video

Tags: html, video, afterglow

I'm using [AfterGlow](https://afterglowplayer.com/)'s html5 video player.  I have created a sample video with a `poster` attribute.  When using a Chrome browser, when I hover my mouse over the video, the `poster` image will quickly disappear and then reappear.  It creates a blinking effect that I do not want.  How do I stop this?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/afterglow/latest/afterglow.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-div">
  <div id="group_1" class="videoContainer">
     <video id="video_s08e01" poster="http://via.placeholder.com/566x318" class="afterglow" width="566" height="318" style="z-index:1;">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/zpo1cxbb/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `style="z-index:-1"` from your video element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pacanga/zpo1cxbb/3/)

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!